# pyside / pyqt: simple way to bind multiple buttons that shares the same functionality

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyqt, pyside

I'm new to PyQt / PySide.

I have a lot of line edit (for displaying file location) and for each line text I have a push button (to display open file dialog).

I have a method:

```
   def selectSelf1(self): 
        """ browse for file dialog """
        myDialog = QtGui.QFileDialog
        self.lineSelf1.setText(myDialog.getOpenFileName())
```

and a push button is binded using the following code

```
    self.btnSelf1.clicked.connect(self.selectSelf1)
```

I have about 20 of those buttons and 20 of those line edits. Is there an easy way to bind all of those button to their corresponding line edits rather than typing out everything.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a list of Buttons and LineEdits, you can use following:

- [`QSignalMapper`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qsignalmapper.html), [another description](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qq/qq10-signalmapper.html)
- [`functools.partial`](http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.partial), like this:

  ```python
  def show_dialog(self, line_edit):
      ...
      line_edit.setText(...)

  for button, line_edit in zip(buttons, line_edits):
      button.clicked.connect(functools.partial(self.show_dialog, line_edit))
  ```
- `lambda`'s

  ```python
  for button, line_edit in ...: 
      button.clicked.connect(lambda : self.show_dialog(line_edit))
  ```

If you are using Qt Designer, and don't have list of buttons and lineedits, but they all have the same naming pattern, you can use some introspection:

```python
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.edit1 = 1
        self.edit2 = 2
        self.edit3 = 3
        self.button1 = 1
        self.button2 = 2
        self.button3 = 3

    def find_attributes(self, name_start):
        return [value for name, value in sorted(self.__dict__.items())
                          if name.startswith(name_start)]

foo = Foo()
print foo.find_attributes('edit')
print foo.find_attributes('button')
```